# CSS attribute selectors vs their shortcuts

Tags: css, class, attributes

.foo is just a shortcut for the attribute selector [class=foo]
and .foo isn't more specific than [class=foo]

```
.foo {
    color:red;
}

[class=foo] {
    color:blue;
}

/* target elements color is blue */
```

however

#bar is more than a mere shortcut for the attribute selector [id=bar]

#bar happens to be more specific than [id=bar]

```
#bar {
    color:red;
}

[id=bar] {
    color:blue;
}

/* target elements color is red */
```

Why is that? Just curious

Comment: The ID selector carries most weight when calculating the specificity as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: .foo is **not** a shortcut for the attribute selector [class=foo]. It's a shortcut for the attribute selector [class~=foo]